# Need of small charge in definition of electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

Why do we need infinitesimally small charge in definition of electric field? Since the test charge cannot exert force on itself, F on test charge will not change whatever the value of test charge q is. So, F/q will be same for any value of test charge. Then why do we need this limit of infinitesimally small charge?

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, test charge should not affect the charge distribution of the source. An *infinitesimal* charge will ensure, for example, that the electric field *it* produces does not redistribute charges on any conductors in your system. A large test charge would polarize nearby objects, thus affecting the field you're trying to measure in the first place.

Comment: This is the answer! An infinitesimal probe-charge is meant to not modify the field.